# Top ID For each record SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a number of different portfolio's, each with their own ID and along with that is the risk number with a run_id

What i am trying to do is for each date, pull the Bps number which is linked to the maximum run_id for each of the portfolios

```
select analysis_date,ptf_id,stat_name,Bps,run_id
from rpt.rm_Report_History 
where analysis_date > '20160102' and criteria_Set= 'Daily' 
and ptf_id in( '10038','10039')
and report_section_group = 'Key_Risk_Figures'
and rm_rcp_param_name = 'Fund'
and stat_class = 'standaloneVaR'
```

which gives the following output

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAtlz.png)

Comment: can you place the desired output?

Comment: please tag the RDMS..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the implementation using cte (applicable to sql server 2008 and later versions).

```
;with cte_1
as
(select analysis_date,ptf_id,stat_name,Bps,run_id,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ptf_id ORDER BY run_id desc) as RNO
from rpt.rm_Report_History 
where analysis_date > '20160102' and criteria_Set= 'Daily' 
and ptf_id in( '10038','10039')
and report_section_group = 'Key_Risk_Figures'
and rm_rcp_param_name = 'Fund'
and stat_class = 'standaloneVaR')

SELECT *
FROM cte_1
WHERE RNO=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with a sub-select that determines the max run_id in the list first and then selects all rows with the criteria AND the max run_id. Since the column is not unique, you can get rid of multiple matches using the `GROUP BY` modifier.

This is a classic min/max in group problem. Some DBMS have better solutions for this, but the one below should probably work in most systems.

```
select analysis_date,ptf_id,stat_name,Bps,run_id
from rpt.rm_Report_History 
where analysis_date > '20160102' and criteria_Set= 'Daily' 
and ptf_id in( '10038','10039')
and report_section_group = 'Key_Risk_Figures'
and rm_rcp_param_name = 'Fund'
and stat_class = 'standaloneVaR'
and run_id = (SELECT max(run_id) FROM rpt.rm_Report_History WHERE
    analysis_date > '20160102'
    and criteria_Set= 'Daily' 
    and ptf_id in( '10038','10039')
    and report_section_group = 'Key_Risk_Figures'
    and rm_rcp_param_name = 'Fund'
    and stat_class = 'standaloneVaR')
GROUP BY run_id
```

EDIT: some DBMS will require you to group by all selected columns:

```
...
GROUP BY analysis_date,ptf_id,stat_name,Bps,run_id
```

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'rpt.rm_Report_History.analysis_date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: okay, I guess you have to group by all selected columns then.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that by tsql you mean SQL server... In which case, throw in a row_number() --Literally my favourite tool in the SQL arsenal

```
select A1.*
from
(
select analysis_date,ptf_id,stat_name,Bps,run_id, row_number() over(partition by ptf_id order by run_id desc) as Run_Order
from rpt.rm_Report_History 
where analysis_date > '20160102' and criteria_Set= 'Daily' 
and ptf_id in( '10038','10039')
and report_section_group = 'Key_Risk_Figures'
and rm_rcp_param_name = 'Fund'
and stat_class = 'standaloneVaR' ) A1
where A1.Run_Order = 1
```